# TryUpdateModel showing the curect data but db is not saving it

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to save a single item into a SQL Server tableusing `TryUpdateModel`. When debugging, I can see the value that needs to be updated, but the `db.SaveChanges()` call is not saving it.

My code:

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult _SubmitRev(int? id)
{
    return PartialView();
}

[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult _SubmitRev(int? id, WriterSubjectReviewVm model)
{
    var loggedInUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var member = db.Members.SingleOrDefault(m => m.ApplicationUserId == loggedInUserId);

    var MySubjectDetails = (from c in db.subjects.Where(s => s.SubjectId == id) select c).AsNoTracking().Single();

    model.rev.SubjectId = (int)id;
    model.sub.SubjectId = MySubjectDetails.SubjectId;

    var bad = MySubjectDetails.Bad;
    model.sub.Bad = bad;

    if (model.rev.GBU == "Bad")
    {
        int iBadRating = Convert.ToInt32(bad);
        iBadRating++;
        model.sub.Bad = iBadRating;
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // TryUpdateModel(model.sub, "Subject");
        TryUpdateModel(model.sub);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return PartialView();
    }

    return PartialView(model);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, I would say that you aren't re-attaching your model back to the context. Let's break it down:

First, your model is coming into the method as a new object:

```
public PartialViewResult _SubmitRev(int? id, WriterSubjectReviewVm model)
```

Then you modify it a bit using data from your DB:

```
    var MySubjectDetails = (from c in db.subjects.Where(s => s.SubjectId == id) select c).AsNoTracking().Single();

    model.rev.SubjectId = (int)id;
    model.sub.SubjectId = MySubjectDetails.SubjectId;
```

**Important to note** that you are pulling `MySubjectDetails` using `.AsNoTracking()`, which pulls it **disconnected** from the context, so this won't automatically save at all unless you re-attach it.

You then assign that disconnected entity to your model:

```
var bad = MySubjectDetails.Bad;

model.sub.Bad = bad;
```

Then you modify some more properties, then you **check if the model is valid and try and save it**:

```
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // TryUpdateModel(model.sub, "Subject");
        TryUpdateModel(model.sub);
        db.SaveChanges();
         return PartialView();

    }
```

At no point have you reconnected your `model` object back to the context (`db`), so when you call `.SaveChanges()`, what are you saving?

### The Solution

At some stage you need to map the properties as posted to your Action (in the form of the `WriterSubjectReviewVm` view model) back onto a data model. Otherwise if that view model is actually a data model (and exists on your DB context in a collection somewhere) then you need to reattach it:

```
db.WriterSubjectReviews.Attach(model)
```

Or something similar - then when you call `SaveChanges()` it will actually save.

Comment: hello,thanks , i'm not sure i understand : i need to do : var xzy=new subject (){Aproperty=..., & so On ?}; or db.subject.Attach-that i have tried and didn't work for me